# Type mismatch error while using a coroutine

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following in my viewModel

```
fun getUsernamePassword(inputUserName:String, inputPassword:String):List<User> = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return repository.getUsernamePassword(inputUserName, inputPassword)
    }
```

However, I am getting an error saying `Type mismatch. Required: List<User> Found:Job` What can I do to solve this error. The ultimate goal is to have the function run on a non-black thread operate and a part from the MAIN THREAD to avoid conflict and errors.

Comment: I'm not sure it should be tagged Java if it's Kotlin, eh?

Comment: Kotlin but it is relevant to Java as well.

Comment: Any help? @corsiKa

Comment: I mean, as a dude who has only done Java for 15 years and nothing to do with Kotlin, no - I don't even know what that first line is trying to say. All I can say is check that `repository.getUsernamePassword(String,String)` returns a List<User> and not a Job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewModelScope.launch` returns a background [Job](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/) where you perform your actual repo operation. In this case, you may need an Observable or LiveData to store the list of users in which your UI needs to act upon.

You can do something like this in your ViewModel:

```
val userList = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()

fun getUsernamePassword(inputUserName:String, inputPassword:String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val list = repository.getUsernamePassword(inputUserName, inputPassword)
    userList.postValue(list)
}
```

In your view, you need to observe to changes to the `userList` of the ViewModel by:

```
viewModel.userList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    // Place UI changes here
})
```

Comment: Okay let me try.

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it and figured it out when I got some understand of what I was doing.